# Please help me understand the concept of sample space, outcome and experiment in this example

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am struggling to understand the concepts and the links between an experiment, the outcomes observed, the quantity of interest one is measuring, and the sample space in probability theory.

For example, suppose I flip a coin twice, and I record the number of heads I get. In this setup, what is the experiment? Is it simply "flipping the coin twice", or is "flipping the coin twice AND recording the number of heads" ? In other words, does the recording of heads constitute an integral part of the experiment, or is this "external" optional add-on?

What are the outcomes here? Are they the number of heads I get or all the possibilities of heads and tails? Does the different order of occurrence of heads and tails constitute different outcomes?

And what would be the sample space? How would I write it this scenario? Is it $\{HH, TT, HT, TH\}$ ? Is it $\{HH, TT, HT\}$ ? Or can I write $\{0,1,2\}$, where the numbers $0, 1, 2$ denote the number of heads I obtain?

Comment: All three are perfectly valid sample spaces, it just depends on what you're actually interested in measuring

Comment: Ok, so the sample space depends on what you are measuring in your experiment, and not necessarily on the experiment itself? @bitesizebo

Comment: So one always needs to define what one is measuring in order to define a sample space? @bitesizebo

Comment: Defining what you're measuring is 100% necessary for everything else in your experiment, including defining the sample space.

Comment: That’s right.  As you stated the problem, you wanted to know the number of heads, so the outcomes were 0, 1, 2.  If you wanted to measure something else , whatever you’re choosing to measure defines the sample space.

Comment: Thanks. What about if I say "flip a coin twice and only record when exactly 1 head is seen". Is this a valid experiment? Would then sample space be $\{HT, TH\}$ ? @RobDukes

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the question is a bit pedantic.

But you say you are "recording the number of heads", so surely it makes most sense for the sample space (which means: the list of possible outcomes) to be {$0,1,2$}, because an outcome is "how many heads you get", and this will either be $0$ heads, $1$ head, or $2$ heads.

But I don't see why you couldn't instead use as the sample space: {$ HH, HT, TH, TT$},

or

{Two H's, One H one T, Two T's}.

Anything that unambiguously describes *all* possible outcomes is a sample space.

Comment: What about if I say "flip a coin twice and only record when exactly 1 head is seen". Is this a valid experiment? Would then sample space be $\{HT, TH\}$ ? @Adam Rubinson

Comment: Not sure. Hmm…….